# Minimum of $\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{x+z}-\frac{1}{x+y+z}$ for $0\leq x+y,y+z,z+x\leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $0\leq x,y,z,x+y,y+z,z+x\leq 1$. What is the minimum of $$F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{x+z}-\frac{1}{x+y+z}?$$

We have $F(1/2,1/2,1/2)=4/3$. Since the constraints are on $x+y,y+z,z+x$ instead of $x,y,z$, taking partial derivative with respect to $x,y,z$ doesn't help much. We cannot change one variable without affecting the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Do the substitution $ a= x+y, b = y + z, c = z + x $, and we have $ 0 \leq a, b, c, \leq 1 $ and we want to minimize

$$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{c}  - \frac{2}{a+b+c}. $$

Comment: Should be $\frac1a+\frac1c-...$, though not material.  Beat me by ~28s.

Comment: I'm sorry, I also want $x,y,z\in[0,1]$. Just edited.

Comment: @Alexi The substitution still holds. Ignore your $x, y, z \in [0, 1]$ constraint, the solution you get meets that constraint.

Comment: @Macavity $c=0$ yields a lower value than $c=1$, but it doesn't correspond to $x,y,z\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Alexi why not? $c = 0 \implies z = x = 0 \in [0, 1]$.  Why don't you work it out yourself, correct the error in the expression, give it a few minutes.

Comment: @Macavity Ok, I get it now. Correcting the error in CalvinLin's expression is quite important here :)